# Strange dates in the data dump

Tags: support, data-dump

I'm toying around with the data dump and I have a question regarding dates.

Take this question for example: [General suggestions for debugging in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4442518/general-suggestions-for-debugging-r)

It says the question was posted 14th December 2010, but the date of the accepted answer is 10th December 2009! What's going on here? ([timemachine](/questions/tagged/timemachine) has lots of good questions/answers, but none related to the type of time machine I'm interested in here.)

Comment: Aha, so two questions were merged and the merged version got the date of the older post? Is my question noise? Should I delete it? (Otherwise, could you post your comment as an answer so I can accept it?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dates look odd because that was the target of merges, as you can see from the [revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/4442518/revisions).

The merged posts are:

- [What is your favorite R debugging trick?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1882734/what-is-your-favorite-r-debugging-trick) - Asked Dec 10 '09
- [Debugging tools for the R language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1169480/debugging-tools-for-the-r-language) - Asked Jul 23 '09

The accepted answer is from the first question above. (You can see that in the answer's edit history.) The dates on the answers or the votes (including accepts) are not changed when a merge happens.